# The type or namespace name 'StiReport' could not be found error

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

I installed StimulSoft2009 and did:

1. Added the .dll files of Stimulreport
2. inserted this code in header:

   using Stimulsoft.Report;
3. added the below code in Button_Click event:

   StiReport report = new StiReport();

   report.Design();

But faced to this error:

```
Error   17  The type or namespace name 'StiReport' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\funfullson\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\cSharpTest\cSharpTest\Form1.cs    23  13  cSharpTest
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Probably you have already found by yourself, but, do you have added the references to the Stimulsoft dll?

Comment: Yes I added.look at 1 point in question.